# TypeError when storing data in a JSON file.(KivyMD Python)

Tags: python, json, kivy, typeerror, kivymd

I want to save some data from the user in a `JSON` file. But when I do that, a `TypeError` is appeared.

- `TypeError: save_bio() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

In this program there are several other times to store data in a `JSON` file. But This does not happen in that cases.

**Here is my Code**

---

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

screen_helper = """

ScreenManager:
    EditBio:
    Studio:

<EditBio>:
    name: 'edit_bio'
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "50dp"
    MDTextField:
        id : bio_text
        text: "Feel Everything"


<Studio>:
    name : 'studio'
    MDRaisedButton:
        text : 'Edit Bio'
        id: edit_profile_pic
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        user_font_size: "25sp"
        on_release : app.edit_bio_dialog()
    MDLabel:
        text:'Bio'
        font_style: 'Subtitle1'
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint : {'center_x':0.255,'center_y':0.538}

"""


class EditBio(Screen):
    pass


class Studio(Screen):
    pass


class Mode(MDApp):
    bio_dialog = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(screen_helper)

    def save_bio(self):
        self.bio = self.root.get_screen('edit_bio').ids.bio_text.text

        self.store_bio.put('BioInfo', bio=self.bio)
        self.bio_changer()

    def bio_changer(self):
        self.root.get_screen('studio').ids.bio.text = f"{self.store_bio.get('BioInfo')['bio']}"

    def on_start(self):
        self.store_bio = JsonStore("bio.json")
        self.root.get_screen('studio').manager.current = 'studio'

    def edit_bio_dialog(self):
        if not self.bio_dialog:
            self.bio_dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Edit Bio:",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=EditBio(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL", font_style='Button', text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color
                    ),
                    MDRaisedButton(
                        text="OK", md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.save_bio
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.bio_dialog.open()


Mode().run()
```

---

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Where is the `save_bio` method being called?  Apparently it's being passed an argument when it shouldn't be passed any (assuming it's being called as a method on an instance of the `Mode` class).  The code you posted doesn't show where this method is used.  That's all that's happening...

Comment: You need to do MVP Darshana. You lost yourself when you are trying to explain what you want when you could explain what is happening and when does it crash. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Iguananaut , I apologize for the mistake. Now I have edited that. Now, `save_bio` method is being called in function `edit_bio_dialog`.  But the error is still happening. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `Button` is released, it calls `self.save_bio()` and passes `self` and the `Button` instance as arguments. If you don't use the `Button` instance in the `save_bio()` method, just add `*args` to its definition:

```
def save_bio(self, *args):
    self.bio = self.root.get_screen('edit_bio').ids.bio_text.text

    self.store_bio.put('BioInfo', bio=self.bio)
    self.bio_changer()
```

Comment: Yes sir. I tried to do that by adding `*args`. But then I faced to an error. (`AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`). It didn't work either.

Comment: @KusalDarshana That would be a different problem then.

Comment: @Iguananaut , so how would I fix the problem? Can you give me a code example that suits for this?

Comment: @KusalDarshana The above answer correctly answers your original question.  For a different error please open a new question, preferably with the [minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  In the code you posted in this question there is no direct reference to `super()` anywhere.  When you post a new question please also post the *full traceback* associated with the error, otherwise it can be difficult to determine where it comes from.  See also https://realpython.com/python-traceback/ and see if you can solve it yourself.

Comment: Okay. Thank you all for helping me.